# How to define array size in a struct from an "external" int defined in input

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, struct, extern

I have a struct with an array in it. The size of this array needs to be 3*input_variable. How can I define a number externally, which is multiplied by an input value, that I can use in a struct to declare the length of an array?

I have tried defining the variable h outside of main as

```
extern h
```

then assigning it's value in main from the input variable.

I have also tried to use (in summary)

```cpp
nt main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int input_variable;
    std::cin << input_variable;

    int h = input_variable * 3;

    void some_function(); // function does some stuff
                          // with the structs

#ifndef ARRAY_SIZING
#define ARRAY_SIZING h
#endif

    return 0;
}

struct _struct_
{
    constexpr std::size_t b = ARRAY_SIZING;
    double* arr[b];
};

int some_function()
{
    // structs are used down here.

    return 0;
}
```

I would love to be able to allocate the size of an array in a struct using an input parameter. Thank you.

Comment: Use a `std::vector` to dynamically size arrays in c++-

Comment: Size of array in C++ is compile time constant, you cannot change that by this naive tricks. Use `std::vector`

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  thanks for your response. I need to use an array, because I am sending the struct using MPI (which can not send structs of vectors).

Comment: @Slava thanks for your comment Slava, I am attempting not to do something naive (that's why I've asked the question). I can't use vectors in this scenario because I need to send vector<struct> in mpi, and struct can not contain vectors in that scenario.

Comment: Then do not send struct but binary buffer

Comment: You cannot do this in C++. What it looks like you are aiming for is a Flexible Array Member. You'll have to do this in C or in a C++ compiler that breaks with the C++ standard and supports flexible array members

Comment: What does the structure really look like? We may be able to offer a viable alternative

Comment: thanks again people. @user4581301 the struct itself is (basically) this simple. it has a few other elements such as int, double, and some other arrays of known size. the array I am trying to dynamically allocate its size is a 2D vector made into a contiguous array, where the 2D vector size is determined by the input (and is defined by the input, but not modified throughout the course of the program.)

Comment: @Slava i was worried I may have to send the message separately from my struct. unfortunately it sounds like this is the case.

Comment: @ming.vase The underlying array of a `std::vector` can be accessed through the `data()` function. There's no need to use a raw array in 1st place.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ since I am sending a std::vector<struct> where in your case the vector would be in the struct, this won't work. in fact this was the exact subject of my only other stack exchange post.

Comment: "since I am sending a std::vector<struct>" and you are hoping to have different size of the same struct inside the vector? That will not work at all even if you will try to use C Flexible Array Member as elements copied into vector and they all will have exactly `sizeof(struct)` size.

Comment: If it was just a wrapper around an array of `double*`, you could do what @πάνταῥεῖ suggested. As soon as you add those extra members, you're up the proverbial creek. Structures generally make for poor IPC messages anyway. You can have padding and alignment issues. Consider serializing. Allocate a big block of bytes. Write in your message and then write in your array. Send. Put message back together at the other side. MPI may have some extra sneaky functions for datatype creation that you can use.

Comment: @Slava no i must be using confusing wording - the size of the struct is identical for all processors and all instances. the number of structs per vector (per processor) varies.

Comment: [Quick google finds `MPI_Type_create_struct`](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Type_create_struct.html). Is it useful to you? I dunno. Maybe it gets you on a worthwhile thread.

Comment: @user4581301 i get what you're saying. i have already had to register the mpi_datatype struct i've created and it is working okay. i've run into a needed revision in the program that requires a little more information per task, leading to this whole question. I'll consider other methods as you suggested. thanks again for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. Plain C-arrays in C++. Mostly never needed. OK, you want to interface to a library function.

My guess is that the library does not expect an array, but a pointer. And since your struct contains an array to pointer to doubles, I assume the lib wants to see a double**.

I hardly can imagine that old libraries use references or pointer to arrays, something like:

```
void function (double* (&array)[10]); // Reference to array
void function (double* (*array)[10]); // Pointer to array
```

because also here you need an array with a size known at compile time.

I'd rather expect something like

```
void function (double** array, size_t size); // Pointer to Pointer to double
```

So, use a `std::vector` like this:

```
std::vector<double *> arr(input_variable * 3);
```

And if you want to hand over the arrays data to the lib functions, then use the vectors `data` function.

```
function (arr.data());
```

You could also create the array with new.

Last hint: Do not use raw pointers.

I hope that I could help a little . . .

Comment: Thank you armin - I upvoted you but because this post put me below 15 rep it didn't show up. gotta love that. I will experiment with your recommendation and comment if it worked.